# JSON format for google pie chart

Tags: javascript, json, google-pie-chart

Hello i have a json file that has data stored like this:

```
[{"cake": "cake1","order": 20},{"cake": "cake2","order": 34},{"cake": "cake3",
  "order": 11}, {"cake": "cake4","order": 11}, {"cake": "cake5", "order": 5}]
```

Now i want to represent the above data using google's pie chart but in order to do accomplish this, it needs to be in this format:

```
[ ['Cake', 'No of Orders'], ['cake1', 20],['cake2',34],
  ['cake3', 11],['cake4',11],['cake5',5] ]
```

google's chart documentation specifies that data should be passed like this:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Cake', 'No of Orders'],
          ['cake1', 20],
          ['cake2', 34],
          ['cake3',  11],
          ['cake4', 11],
          ['cake5', 5]
        ]);
```

Please how does one change the original format above into a list containing severals list in javascript. Much help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps using the [array `.map()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to change the format of the data, and then the [array `.unshift()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) to insert the headings at the beginning of the new array:

```
var input = [{"cake": "cake1","order": 20},{"cake": "cake2","order": 34},
             {"cake": "cake3", "order": 11}, {"cake": "cake4","order": 11},
             {"cake": "cake5", "order": 5}];

var output = input.map(function(item) { return [item.cake, item.order]; });

output.unshift(["Cake", "No of Orders"]);

var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this? Try running this in jsbin.

```
var a = [{"cake": "cake1","order": 20},{"cake": "cake2","order": 34},{"cake": "cake3",
  "order": 11}, {"cake": "cake4","order": 11}, {"cake": "cake5", "order": 5}];

function cakeFormat(a){
  var first = [];
  console.log(a);
  // noprotect
  for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
    for(var j in a[i]){
      first.push([j, a[i][j]]);
    }
  }

  var final = [["Cake", "No of Orders"]];

  for(var k = 0; k < (first.length - 1);){
    final.push([first[k][1], first[k+1][1]]);
    k = k + 2;
  }

  return final;
}

cakeFormat(a);
```